# hashing passwords with pbkdf2 crypto does not work correctly

Tags: node.js, hash, passwords, password-encryption

Password security is not my strong suit. Please help me out.

I use node.js 4.2.3 express 4.13.3. I found some examples to hash and salt passwords with crypto's pbkdf2.

Here is my code.

```
var salt = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('base64');
console.log("salt  >  "+salt);
crypto.pbkdf2(pass, salt , 10000, 150, 'sha512',function(err, derivedKey) {
    pass = derivedKey.toString('hex');
});
```

The final derivedKey does not include the salt. What am I missing? Should I join the two strings manually before saving?

Why some examples use `base64` and others `hex`? To get different string lenghts? What is the default, so I can use it?

Why not to use `basic64` in both salt and hashed password?

Is the final derivedKey string UTF8? Or this has to do only with the database it gets saved? My database is in UTF8.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) if you're not too familiar with security or best practices, it's rather easy to get it setup.  (at-least in comparison to pbkdf2). It's as simple as `bcrypt.hash('password', 8, function(err, hash) { // store hash
});`

Comment: @AshleyB Yeah, i saw bcrypt ,but I chose pbkdf2 because its baked in node, not a module that maybe has issues. Also bcrypt demands to install alot of things as dependencies. Anyway, I would like to get some answers to my original post, I am curious. Also, do you know if the bcrypt is reliable? Does it have major issues? Thanks. Merry Christmas buddy

Comment: The Bcrypt module I linked is used alot (165k downloads/month) and is maintained, the only downside would be the prerequisites (mainly node-gyp). Security-wise, both are widely used as a password hashing function. One thing I would mention is that you are more likely to mess up using pbkdf2 if you're unfamiliar with it (as you say you are), whereas with Bcrypt it's much harder to get things wrong due to the simplicity.

Comment: @AshleyB bcrypt and node-gyp each have a couple of prerequisites and also, I dont know if it is wise to install those programs (visual studio and windows sdk) in a server, security-wise. Will those cause a security problem or make the system weak? For now I built on my laptop, but the server runs Windows Server , the latest verion if I remeber correctly. Anyhow, I find a piece about pbkdf2 on a node cookbook, will test and if I fail to use it correctly, I will use bcrypt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, store the salt yourself, separately, unencrypted.  Make sure it's randomly generated.

**More importantly, you're crippling your PBKDF2 encryption by asking for 150 bytes (bytes per [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback)) of key length** - SHA512 is a fantastic choice, but it only provides 64 bytes of native output.  To get 10,000 iterations of 150 bytes of output, [PBKDF2/RFC2898](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) is going to execute 30,000 times, while an offline attacker will only need to run 10,000 iterations and match the first 64 bytes (if the first 64 match, then the rest will too); ***you gave them a 3:1 advantage for free!***

Instead, if you're happy with the work factor, you should use 30,000 iterations of 64 bytes of output - you'll spend the same amount of time, no difference, but the attacker now has to do 30,000 iterations too, so you took away their 3:1 advantage!

When you pass the salt to the PBKDF2 function, if you can, just pass in the pure binary.  Also, the node.js docs say - reasonably "It is recommended that the salts are random and their lengths are greater than 16 bytes."  This means binary 16 bytes, before the base64 or hex or whatever conversion if you want one.

You can save both salt and derivedkey as BINARY of the correct length for the most efficient storage (then you don't have to worry about UTF-x vs. ASCII), or you can convert one or both to BASE64 or hexadecimal, and then convert back to binary as required.  Base64 vs hex vs binary is irrelevant as long as the conversions are reconverted as needed.

I'd also make the number of iterations a stored field, so you can easily increase it in the years to come, and include a field for the "version" of password hashing used, so you can easily change your algorithm in the years to come if need be as well.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption works with data, not strings, this includes the encryption key. PBKDF2 produces a data key, which can be easily converted to a string, this conversion is necessary because many data bytes have no corresponding print character or unicode  code point. Many scripting languages do not handle data well so the data is many times converted to Base64 or hexadecimal (hex).

You can use Base64 or hexadecimal for the salt and hashed password, just be consistent on all uses.

The salt and iteration count need to be the same for creating an checking, you will need to combine them or save them separately.

Your code is converting the derived key to hexadecimal, that is fine and base64 would also be fine. Again this is necessary because not all data bytes are UTF-8.

Comment: Ok, so to be clear, do I have to do `finalPassword = salt+hash` before saving?  Salt confuses me on how to use it and why its not in the hash. Thanks

Comment: Since the salt is different for each password it also needs to be saved. The salt is an input and the hash is an output. PBKDF2 is a primitive function that has several usages, hashing passwords is just one. For some usages they do not need to be combined, one example is creating an encryption key which is used for the encryption and only the salt is saved.