# how to safely store the password salt

Tags: hash, passwords, password-protection, salt

I use `pbkdf2` to salt and hash passwords. I get that the salt must be unencrypted and accessible so I can use it again in validation. Each password's salt must be accessible so I can salt and hash the to-be-validated password and compare it with the stored one.

I was thinking to store the salt like so

Assuming salt is always a string with a fixed lenght, eg, 10 characters

```
finalPassword = salt + password;
//save finalPassword in the db
```

and then to validate

```
salt = getFirst10CharsOf (finalPassword);

hash to-be-validated password with that salt

compare hashed password with the saved one
```

My question is, if a hacker is smart enough to get my hashed passwords, what stops her to see the `getFirst10CharsOf` part in my code and get a couple of salts, so she can easily decrypt a couple of hashes?

I found a lot a theory, but I dont have a clue how to safely store salts in **practice**. So they can always be accesible just to the validation code, but not to everyone.

Thanks

Comment: This question seems to be an extension of this other [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34459088/451475).

Comment: @zaph Yes, it is specified on the salt part and asks if my idea of saving a salt is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The salt does not need to be secret, it is used for several things: 1. make using rainbow tables more difficult and 2. insuring that two passwords do not hash to the same value so that if one is compromised other same passwords are not (different hashes).

Answer (score 2):

> what stops her to see the getFirst10CharsOf part in my code and get a couple of salts,

Nothing

> so she can easily decrypt a couple of hashes?

The point of using a one-way hash is that you *can't* decrypt them (not even with the salt).

The point of using a salt (and a different one each time) is that you can't brute force them with a rainbow table.

> I dont have a clue how to safely store salts in practice.

Just store them with the hashed password. There's no need to keep them inaccessible.

> So they can always be accesible just to the validation code, but not to everyone.

If it was possible to store data somewhere that your code could access but someone will illicit access to the system the code runs on could no, then there would be no need to hash passwords in the first place.

Comment: Nice answer. So, to be clear, my approach is safe and I should deploy it?

Comment: @slevin - Actually a salt should be longer than 10 characters. There is a widely used [common format](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.password.storing-salts), how a salt can be stored. I would recommend to find an existing BCrypt/PBKDF2 library, which generates a safe salt and produces this future proof format.